# How to serve files from a second server in Drupal 6?

Tags: files, cdn

I have bandwidth limitations for a busy and image-heavy D6 site so I decided to outsource my `/webroot/site/default/files` to my second server which is almost idle.

I tried to do so using [CDN](http://drupal.org/project/cdn) module, which I previously used successfully with a CDN provider. So I moved (and rsynced) all the files to the second server and set up a `cdn.mydomain.com` there. I could wget images directly off the second server but for some reason I could not manage to display images on the site.

Due to my budget constraints I can not use S3 or any commercial CDN for this purpose. So I am wondering what you guys suggest to serve static files from my second server?

Comment: Is Amazon Cloudfront our of your price range?  It works well with CDN in origin pull mode.

Comment: Unfortunately its too expensive for me.

Comment: Questions about recommended hosting are off-topic as per [FAQ].

Comment: kiamlaluno, have you ever read the post before closing it?! I really doubt. My question has nothing to do with asking a provider. It is a purely technical question. It is not my fault that others suggested a commercial solution in comments as solution and I briefly replied.

Comment: I reaplaced 'outsourcing' with a more appropriate phrase in my question to avoid possible misunderstanding.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it was a legitimate question about how to serve files from a secondary server.

Comment: Thanks jhedstrom. I was also VERY surprised. I did not expect this from kiamlaluno.

Comment: "Due to my budget constraints I can not use S3 or any commercial CDN for this purpose. So I am wondering what you guys suggest to serve static files from my second server?" This is a shopping question, if you are not talking about a module to use. Since you are asking about a CDN provider, I take that means a server, not a module. (See also the question  title.) If you are asking about a server you setup, you should make that clear, but keep in mind that it is not [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) if you don't have a network distributed over the territory.

Comment: The question is legitimate, but it is not a question for this very site. First, it is not a Drupal specific question, if not for the fact you could be interested in a CDN provider for which there is a module to support it. (The CDN module should support all of them, though.) Second, shopping questions are not welcome on Stack Exchange; see [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: After having read the linked to blogpost, I feel like the close is correct. The question is certainly legitimate, but in it's current form doesn't fit the site.

Comment: The question is relevant to Drupal, specifically, it is stated that wget works, but images do not--I'd guess this is due to Imagecache, which would not work without some custom 404-handling on the secondary server.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The mere fact that I mentioned 'budget' does not make it a shopping question. Indeed it was just a proactive way to avoid suggestions like go get a S3 etc. And it is absolutely a Drupal questioin. Sorry, but I expect a more open-minded approach from you, how have been one of the most helpful and respected moderators.